# Login for iPhone apps no longer working using Google App account following transition

Tags: iphone, google-workspace

I maintain a Google Apps account using my own domain.

Since the transition I am no longer able to use my Google App email address to log into a couple of iPhone apps, namely Feedly and Reeder which aggregate my Google Reader feeds.

I am still able to access my email, calendar, etc using the account without problems.

Is there any configuration on the Google Apps side that I am missing? Is this an API issue that the App developers have missed?

Answer (score 1):

On your domain management page, make sure the Google Reader service is turned on for your Google Apps accounts. [Here is the help page for turning services on or off](https://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182442).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the cause - the service is turned on :(